# create tabular list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am going to create two tabular list into my website with jquery i'm done it with tabs functionfrom jquery website but unfortunately it doesn't work on my website:
the code that i have use is:

```
<div id="best_tabs">
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                            <li><a href="#tab_1">جدیدترین</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab_2">محبوب ترین</a></li>
                        </ul>
                            <div id="tab_1">
                                <ul>
                                                                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/post-the-next-day/">post the next day</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/post-the-next-day/">post the next day</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/entire-post/">entire post</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/entire-post/">entire post</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/hello-world/">Hello world!</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/hello-world/">Hello world!</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b4%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%aa-%d9%86%d9%81%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%ae%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%85-%d9%85%db%8c-%da%a9%d9%86%d8%af/">شرکت نفت استخدام می کند</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b4%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%aa-%d9%86%d9%81%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%ae%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%85-%d9%85%db%8c-%da%a9%d9%86%d8%af/">شرکت نفت استخدام می کند</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%84%d9%88%d8%af-%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b2%db%8c%da%a9-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%be%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3/">دانلود موزیک ابراهیم پارس</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%84%d9%88%d8%af-%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b2%db%8c%da%a9-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%be%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3/">دانلود موزیک ابراهیم پارس</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7%db%8c-%d9%85%d8%a8%d8%aa%d9%86%db%8c-%d8%a8%d8%b1-%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7/">دنیای مبتنی بر سینما</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7%db%8c-%d9%85%d8%a8%d8%aa%d9%86%db%8c-%d8%a8%d8%b1-%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7/">دنیای مبتنی بر سینما</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7-%d9%86%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af-%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7-%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa/">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7-%d9%86%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af-%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7-%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa/">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%81%d9%86%d8%ac%db%8c/">باب اسفنجی</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%81%d9%86%d8%ac%db%8c/">باب اسفنجی</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d9%87%d8%a7/">فوتبالیست ها</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d9%87%d8%a7/">فوتبالیست ها</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84-%d9%84%db%8c%d9%86%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%86/">فوتبال لینجان</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84-%d9%84%db%8c%d9%86%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%86/">فوتبال لینجان</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%d9%88%d9%86%db%8c%da%a9/">سونیک</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%d9%88%d9%86%db%8c%da%a9/">سونیک</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%ad%d8%af/">سیساست واحد</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%ad%d8%af/">سیساست واحد</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a7%d8%ae%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%ac%d8%af%db%8c%d8%af/">اخبار جدید</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a7%d8%ae%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%ac%d8%af%db%8c%d8%af/">اخبار جدید</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tab_2">

                                    <ul>

                                                                    <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b4%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%aa-%d9%86%d9%81%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%ae%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%85-%d9%85%db%8c-%da%a9%d9%86%d8%af/">شرکت نفت استخدام می کند</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7%db%8c-%d9%85%d8%a8%d8%aa%d9%86%db%8c-%d8%a8%d8%b1-%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7/">دنیای مبتنی بر سینما</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%84%d9%88%d8%af-%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b2%db%8c%da%a9-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%be%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3/">دانلود موزیک ابراهیم پارس</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%81%d9%86%d8%ac%db%8c/">باب اسفنجی</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/hello-world/">Hello world!</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84-%d9%84%db%8c%d9%86%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%86/">فوتبال لینجان</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%b1/">دلار</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7-%d9%86%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af-%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7-%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa/">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

and also this is my jquery effort:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   

        $(function() {
                $( "#best_tabs" ).tabs();
                });

    });
```

[this is my website link](http://2day.hisend.ir/category/%D8%AA%D8%A6%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D9%88-%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7/)

as you see in link above no one of two tab work

Comment: Are you including the JqueryUI javascript file in your HTML page?

Comment: yes, im included both jquery and jquery ui

Comment: I just tried: $( "#best_tabs" ).tabs(); on your site in the console. and it worked. This means you are doing everything correct but the function is getting ran before jquery or jqueryUI is loaded. The problem is a race condition.

Comment: Add how you are calling your script tags.

Comment: the jquery and jquery ui are above of my code and also i'm wrap the code with $(document).ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="best_tabs">
                    <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li><a href="#tab_1">جدیدترین</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab_2">محبوب ترین</a></li>
                    </ul>
                        <div id="tab_1">
                            <ul>
                                                                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/post-the-next-day/">post the next day</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/post-the-next-day/">post the next day</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/entire-post/">entire post</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/entire-post/">entire post</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/hello-world/">Hello world!</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/hello-world/">Hello world!</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b4%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%aa-%d9%86%d9%81%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%ae%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%85-%d9%85%db%8c-%da%a9%d9%86%d8%af/">شرکت نفت استخدام می کند</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b4%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%aa-%d9%86%d9%81%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%ae%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%85-%d9%85%db%8c-%da%a9%d9%86%d8%af/">شرکت نفت استخدام می کند</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%84%d9%88%d8%af-%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b2%db%8c%da%a9-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%be%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3/">دانلود موزیک ابراهیم پارس</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%84%d9%88%d8%af-%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b2%db%8c%da%a9-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%be%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3/">دانلود موزیک ابراهیم پارس</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7%db%8c-%d9%85%d8%a8%d8%aa%d9%86%db%8c-%d8%a8%d8%b1-%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7/">دنیای مبتنی بر سینما</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7%db%8c-%d9%85%d8%a8%d8%aa%d9%86%db%8c-%d8%a8%d8%b1-%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7/">دنیای مبتنی بر سینما</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7-%d9%86%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af-%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7-%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa/">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7-%d9%86%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af-%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7-%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa/">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%81%d9%86%d8%ac%db%8c/">باب اسفنجی</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%81%d9%86%d8%ac%db%8c/">باب اسفنجی</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d9%87%d8%a7/">فوتبالیست ها</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d9%87%d8%a7/">فوتبالیست ها</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84-%d9%84%db%8c%d9%86%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%86/">فوتبال لینجان</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84-%d9%84%db%8c%d9%86%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%86/">فوتبال لینجان</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%d9%88%d9%86%db%8c%da%a9/">سونیک</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%d9%88%d9%86%db%8c%da%a9/">سونیک</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%ad%d8%af/">سیساست واحد</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa-%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%ad%d8%af/">سیساست واحد</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a7%d8%ae%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%ac%d8%af%db%8c%d8%af/">اخبار جدید</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a7%d8%ae%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%ac%d8%af%db%8c%d8%af/">اخبار جدید</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab_2">

                                <ul>

                                                                <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%85%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b5%d9%84%d8%ad-%d9%87%d8%b3%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85/">ما خواستار صلح هستیم</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b4%d8%b1%da%a9%d8%aa-%d9%86%d9%81%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%ae%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%85-%d9%85%db%8c-%da%a9%d9%86%d8%af/">شرکت نفت استخدام می کند</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7%db%8c-%d9%85%d8%a8%d8%aa%d9%86%db%8c-%d8%a8%d8%b1-%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7/">دنیای مبتنی بر سینما</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%84%d9%88%d8%af-%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b2%db%8c%da%a9-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%87%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%be%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3/">دانلود موزیک ابراهیم پارس</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%ae%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%b1%da%af-%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b3%d8%aa/">تا خون در رگ ماست</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%81%d9%86%d8%ac%db%8c/">باب اسفنجی</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/hello-world/">Hello world!</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d9%81%d9%88%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%84-%d9%84%db%8c%d9%86%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%86/">فوتبال لینجان</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%af%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%b1/">دلار</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://2day.hisend.ir/%d8%b3%db%8c%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7-%d9%86%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af-%d8%af%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7-%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa/">سینما نباشد دنیا نیست</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
</div>
```